# PHP: $_GET[''] superglobal does not fetch the value from URL after Cleaning the URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have a problem with $_GET[''].
Before applying .htaccess rules on URL every things was working fine, when I clean the URL's with .htaccess file now the echo $_GET['id'] give me this error **(Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\Test\show.php on line 3)**. The new clean URL's work fine without parameter but when I tried to send parameter it does not send id. 
I don't Know what to do. I have searched for this problem more then 10 hours but no result.

**my .htaccess file content:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) show.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

**the show.php page where I want to display the values from URL**

```
<?php
$myvar = $_GET['id']."<br>";
$myvar1 = $_GET['name'];
echo $myvar;
echo $myvar1;
?>
```

**this URL have no problem  (http://localhost/Test/show.php?id=120&name=ahmad)**

**but in this url (http://localhost/Test/show/120/ahmad) this error is happening **

***Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\Test\show.php on line 3
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\Test\show.php on line 4***

I have dis comment the mod_rewrite.os in httpd.conf file as will.

please help me thanks.

Comment: What about $_GET['name'] can you get it from url "http://localhost/Test/show/120/ahmad" ??

Comment: no I can't get both of them  can't get id and  name  as well

Comment: Perhaps `MultiViews` are enabled on your apache server. Try adding `Options -MultiViews` line to your htaccess and then test the url again

Answer (score 0):

Change your RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The second one means if the path is NOT a file on the server, so that's what you want.  I guess the first one means only if the path IS a file.

Comment: it still not working . I will try to install another server in my PC if it works . Thanks you (;

Comment: It looks like my Wamp server has problem because I install xampp it work fine with Thanks you :)